# react-native-elements: Header rendering unexpected bottom border

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm experiencing a weird issue with the Header component from react-native-elements.
Here's what I'm seeing:
[image]

and here's the code:

```
<Header
    leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#85106a',  }}
    rightComponent={<Avatar
        small
        rounded
        source={{uri: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg"}}
        onPress={() => console.log("Works!")}
        activeOpacity={0.7}
    />}
    statusBarProps={{ barStyle: 'dark-content', translucent: true }}
/>
```

I want the border on the bottom to be the same colour as the hamburger menu. I looked through the documentation of the component, but didn't find anything of the essence.

Any ideas are much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have try your project, so you need to add props `containerStyle` on header component and change the style like this :

```
<Header
  leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#85106a',  }}
  rightComponent={<Avatar
                small
                rounded
                source={{uri: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg"}}
                onPress={() => console.log("Works!")}
                activeOpacity={0.7}
            />}
  statusBarProps={{ barStyle: 'dark-content', translucent: true }}
  containerStyle={{ borderBottomColor:'#85106a',borderBottomWidth:1 }}
/>
```

And then the result :

[image]

I hope this answer can help you

Comment: How about that @Trevor Donahue, is it working on your project ?

Comment: On the newest version you should use containerStyle instead of outerContainerStyles. I use borderBottomColor:'transparent', to ensure it is not shown

Answer (score 5):

Note to the future visitors of this post:

On the latest version of react-native-elements (1.1.0), the props to override the style of the header container `outerContainerStyles` has been changed into `containerStyle`